# How do I get the ListView reverse position in android?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, listview, android-studio

I use a `ListView` to show a history of a record. I use database in order to store and pull the record into the `ListView`. Now, I want to pull this record again by doing this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        positions = position;
        checkdata();
    }
}
```

and get the data from the database using the positions and turning into id

```
public void checkdata() {
    String[] columns = {"id", "titleexam", "address", "time", "score", "Examdata", "totalscore", "hour", "min", "sec", "timedis"};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("record", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.move(positions);
    ExamRecord recordr = new ExamRecord(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10));
    title = cursor.getString(1);
    data = cursor.getString(5);
}
```

The problem begin when I sort the `ListView` in reverse, because the `ListView` will show all the recent record at the top and the older ones at the bottom using this in the adapter to show it at the user.

```
Collections.reverse(records);
```

How can I get the position(id) on the reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

you have many options
option 1: you can reverse query order based on one column

```
 Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.query("record", columns, null, null, null, null yourColumn+" DESC");
```

option 2: if you send data on ArrayList data structure you can reverse it
 `Collections.reverse(YourList);`

option 3: you can reverse ListView it self i don't it will work for your question

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

Comment: what does the "transcriptMode" do?

Comment: look at android dev documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode